# Where to position a tracking image with an email?

Tags: email, html-email, tracking

Have a client that we made an HTML email for, but there is so much content that GMAIL is cutting the email off and states to view entire email click here. That is fine, but it cuts our tracking image off, which then throws off the open rates. I want to avoid an HTML or CSS compiler. Is it safe to put a tracking image near the top? I mean it works putting it at the top...but what is the best practice? I have done several searches and haven't really found a good solution. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: You can put the tracking pixel anywhere. If your emails are too large for Gmail, your customers are not looking at your emails in the first place. That should be your biggest concern.

Comment: Agree with @gwally here. You primary concern should be the fact it's getting clipped, you should look at reducing content to bring it under the 106Kb limit.

If that's not an option, place it at the very top before any content, would barely be noticed.

Comment: Adding to the above, Gmail uses proxy for all images which means you're image will get downloaded by Gmail and served from their proxy which works mean the tracking info might be a little skewed.